# BATxxx, BAVxxx, BASxxx, the meaning of first three letters in various diode names

Tags: diodes, schottky

As known, there are various diodes named BATxxx, BAVxxx, BASxxx. Then what's the meaning of 'BAT', 'BAV', 'BAS'?

Thanks.

Comment: seems like pro-electron but it's not.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> As known, there are various Schottky diodes named BATxxx, BAVxxx, BASxxx. Then what's the meaning of 'BAT', 'BAV', 'BAS'?

This is the basic [Pro Electron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pro_Electron) scheme.

It's an old naming convention. B=Silicon, to distinguish it from all those Germanium devices out there ;-). A is a diode, as opposed to C, a transistor. For instance an electronics set I had in the 1960s had an AC126 germanium transistor in it.

Your assertion about all V and S diodes being schottkies is incorrect though. For instance, here are two counter examples. A [BAV99](https://www.vishay.com/docs/85718/bav99.pdf) is an ordinary silicon diode, not a schottky. A [BAS116](https://assets.nexperia.com/documents/data-sheet/BAS116.pdf) is an ultra-low leakage otherwise ordinary silicon diode, not a schottky.

A [BAT54](https://www.vishay.com/docs/85508/bat54.pdf) *is* a schottky. Now whether *all* BATxxx diodes are schottkies, and any V or S ones are, I've not the patience to find out.

[This](https://www.electronics-notes.com/articles/electronic_components/transistor/transistor-codes-numbering.php) source asserts that

> Subsequent characters
>
> The characters following the first two letters form the serial number of the device. Those intended for domestic use have three numbers, but those intended for commercial or industrial use have letter followed by two numbers, i.e. A10 - Z99.

... which suggests that T, V and S have little meaning beyond a random character making up the part's serial number.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I've edit the tile. Now, are there some special meaning for 'T', 'V', 'S'?